# error in wordpress in Advanced Flat Rate Shipping For WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have an error in Advanced Flat Rate Shipping For WooCommerce plugin, everytime i try to activate it the dashboard crash and show this error:

```
An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 191 of the file /home/u922158803/domains/janelle-eg.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-extra-flat-rate/includes/class-advanced-flat-rate-shipping-for-woocommerce.php. Error message: Uncaught Error: Class "AFRSM_Shipping_Method" not found in /home/u922158803/domains/janelle-eg.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-extra-flat-rate/includes/class-advanced-flat-rate-shipping-for-woocommerce.php:191
Stack trace:
#0 /home/u922158803/domains/janelle-eg.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): Advanced_Flat_Rate_Shipping_For_WooCommerce_Pro->afrsm_pro_register_shipping_method_class()
#1 /home/u922158803/domains/janelle-eg.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#2 /home/u922158803/domains/janelle-eg.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shipping.php(148): apply_filters()
#3 /home/u922158803/domains/janelle-eg.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shipping-zone.php(166): WC_Shipping->get_shipping_method_class_names()
#4 /home/u922158803/domains/janelle-eg.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shipping-zones.php(36): WC_Shipping_Zone->get_shipping_methods()
#5 /home/u922158803/domains/janelle-eg.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/src/Shipping/ShippingController.php(315): WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones()
#6 /home/u922158803/domains/janelle-eg.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): AutomatticWooCommerceBlocksShippingShippingController->hydrate_client_settings()
#7 /home/u922158803/domains/janelle-eg.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#8 /home/u922158803/domains/janelle-eg.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#9 /home/u922158803/domains/janelle-eg.com/public_html/wp-admin/admin-header.php(118): do_action()
#10 /home/u922158803/domains/janelle-eg.com/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(239): require_once('/home/u92215880...')
#11 {main}
  thrown
```

I tried to deactivate all the plugins and avreything works fine and i activated all the plugins except Advanced Flat Rate Shipping For WooCommerce plugin and also it works fine but when i activate Advanced Flat Rate Shipping For WooCommerce plugin it crashes the website and the admin dashboard of WordPress
so can anyone tell me what's the error in this plugin and how to fix it ??

thanks in advance,

i tried deactivating all the plugins and it works fine and when i deactivate Advanced Flat Rate Shipping For WooCommerce plugin it works fine but i need this plugin to work

Comment: That's a commercial plugin. The WooCommerce support people do a good job. If you haven't asked them for help it's worth your time.

Comment: i tried to contact them but they didn't reply

Answer (score 0):

It is written in the error message itself:

> An **error of type E_ERROR** was caused **in line 191** of the **file
> /home/u922158803/domains/janelle-eg.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-extra-flat-rate/includes/class-advanced-flat-rate-shipping-for-woocommerce.php.**

And then it tells you what is wrong:

> Error message: Uncaught Error: **Class "AFRSM_Shipping_Method" not found**
> in
> /home/u922158803/domains/janelle-eg.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-extra-flat-rate/includes/class-advanced-flat-rate-shipping-for-woocommerce.php:191

It can't find the class `AFRSM_Shipping_Method` in the file which belongs to the plugin.

You should contact the Author of the plugin, alternatively you could also try to reinstall the plugin.

Comment: it was working fine in the beginning but when i tried to add a shipping method it broke..so if i reinstall it, will all my work will be delete it for this plugin right ?